# psql - select specific property from jsonb array of object

Tags: psql, jsonb

I have jsonb column that contains an array such as:

```
[
  {"name": "Alice", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Bob", "age": 29},
  {"name": "John", "age": 32}
]
```

How can I make a query so that it returns only the names in a table such as:

```
NAME
----
Alice
Bob
John
```

Thank you